# The argument type '(On....) -> Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type `(Object) -> void`

Tags: dart

I've enabled strict mode in my Dart code-base today and have fixed most of the warnings and errors. 
This one I'm not sure how to fix ...

This is my method signature:

```
StreamSubscription listen(Type eventType, void onData(Object event), { Function onError, void onDone(), bool cancelOnError}) {

   ... code here ...

}
```

When doing: `_bus.listen(OnRowDoubleClick, (OnRowDoubleClick event){`
I'm getting

```
The argument type '(OnRowDoubleClick) -> Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type `(Object) -> void`
```

I can change the method signature to

```
StreamSubscription listen(Type eventType, Null onData(Object event), {...`,
```

(which doesn't make sense since I don't actually want to return anything), the error changes to

```
The argument type '(OnRowDoubleClick) -> Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type `(Object) -> Null`
```

Changing the method call to this:

```
_bus.listen(OnRowDoubleClick, (event){
```

The error goes away, but now I have to cast `event as OnRowDoubleClick` the whole time.

Is there a better way of dong this?

*** Solution ***

Solution is to mark the listener with T:

```
StreamSubscription listen<T>(Type eventType, Null onData(T event), {
```

Now you can call `_bus.listen<OnRowDoubleClick>(OnRowDoubleClick, (event){` and the event will be of type `OnRowDoubleClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `listen` expects the argument `onData` to be a function that takes any Dart `Object` as an argument. You are passing a function that only takes `OnRowDoubleClick` as an argument, so strong mode gives an error.

You could change your `listen` method so that it takes a type parameter, take a look at [`Stream#listen`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) for an example.

Comment: How would I define that the input type is of T without marking the whole class as of type T? The idea is to be able to have multiple listeners of different types on the same bus instance, as soon as I mark the class of type T, then I can only do one type per instance? Kotlin allows you to do `inline fun <reified T : Any> String.fromJson(): T {} ` in which case I can call `fromJson<OnRowDoubleClick>()`, how would I do this in Dart?

Comment: You can add a type annotation to your `listen` function, for example:

`StreamSubscription listen<T>(void onData(T event), { Function onError, void onDone(), bool cancelOnError})`

See http://news.dartlang.org/2016/12/dart-121-generic-method-syntax.html for more details

Comment: That is very cool! I knew Dart had to have such a feature :-D
thanks Harry!